# Incorporate Grid Layout for Files in JTree Hierarchy

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtree

For a specific project, I have to develop a grid/tile like layout for all non-directory files within a JTree component. Below is an example of the desired end result, not embedded since I do not have the required reputation:

[image]

The JTree must maintain its standard structure until files are reached. Notice how the directory 'Demo_folder' contains both a directory and five files laid out in tiles, meaning they also have to function together and not just within a directory of only files. Are there any alternatives to develop this without forcing a JPanel with a grid(bag) layout manager inside of the JTree? I realize there are much better alternatives, such as a file system similar to Windows Explorer with a split pane and the files organized in tiles, but this is a requirement I cannot skip over. I am not looking for code to complete this, just guidance towards some other format that would produce this result more efficiently. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It "might" be possible through the use of a custom `TreeCellRenderer`, but I don't think you'll get the functionality you're really after, as renderers are not "live" components

Comment: Also consider this alternative [view component](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).